# How to create full graph from vertex data frame with igraph?

Tags: r, graphs

Here is a DF which I take as a representation of my future vertices:

```
Id   Name
01   Alpha
02   Beta
03   Delta
04   Epsilon
```

I want to get an igraph representation of a full graph with these nodes in R. As far as I know igraph's `graph.full` function cannot take DF as input and I cannot really want to create an intermediary DF with all possible conection combination. Any clever idea?

Answer (score 1):

All full graphs of the same order and direction are the same, so just make a full graph of the right size and then put your vertex data on the vertices:

```
> d = data.frame(Id=c("01","02","03","04"),Name=c("Alpha","Beta","Delta","Epsilon"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> d
  Id    Name
1 01   Alpha
2 02    Beta
3 03   Delta
4 04 Epsilon
> g = graph.full(nrow(d))
> V(g)$Name = d$Name
> V(g)$Id = d$Id
```